# Jquery bootstrap dialog open error

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a link in my page. It is linked to a div in the same page. It is supposed to open a dialog box. But I am getting an error in the console.

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

My code:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forgot-pop">Forgot password</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="forgot-pop" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="login-wrap">
                    <h3>
                        FORGOT PASSWORD</h3>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

The dialog does not open, instead I see this error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load javascript:void(0);. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

I have included, jquery & bootstrap. 
So what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to access any cross site domain content before you open the dialog?

Comment: Hi akshay, no, absolutely not. It is a div within same page.

Comment: you have installed web server in your local PC?

Comment: Hi Guru, Please spare silly questions. It an asp.net project running in VS

Answer (score 1):

This seems to happen in Chrome when you add

> href="javascript:"

or similar to your a tag. Using a hash in stead works but I really prefer javascript:

(btw the void(0) part isn't needed)